# JQuery Not Setting Rails 5.2 hidden_field Value

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a fairly simple setup in my Rails 5.2 `simple_form` in which JQuery is supposed to set a `hidden_field` based on which selector div is clicked.  The html/erb looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@source) do |f| %>
  ...
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div id="selector-journal" class="selector active">Journal Article</div>
          <div id="selector-book" class="selector">Book</div>
          <div id="selector-website" class="selector">Website</div>
          <%= f.hidden_field :source_type, id: "source" %>
        </div> <!-- row -->
...
<% end %>
```

And the JQuery looks like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mdb-select').materialSelect();
    $('.datepicker').pickadate();
    tinymce.init({
      selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
      plugins: "code",
      toolbar: "code",
      menubar: "tools"
    });

    if ($("#source").val("") ) {
      $('.selector').removeClass("active");
    };

    if ($("#source").val( "Journal") ){
      $('#selector-journal').addClass("active");
    } else if ($("#source").val( "Book") ){
      $('#selector-book').addClass("active");
    } else if ($("#source").val( "Website") ){
      $('#selector-website').addClass("active");
    }

    $('#selector-journal').click(function(){
      $('.selector').removeClass("active");
      $('#selector-journal').addClass("active");
      $('.source-info-section').addClass("hidden");
      $('#journal-info').removeClass("hidden");
      $('#source').val("Journal");
    });
    $('#selector-book').click(function(){
      $('.selector').removeClass("active");
      $('#selector-book').addClass("active");
      $('.source-info-section').addClass("hidden");
      $('#book-info').removeClass("hidden");
      $('#source').val("Book");
    });
    $('#selector-website').click(function(){
      $('.selector').removeClass("active");
      $('#selector-website').addClass("active");
      $('.source-info-section').addClass("hidden");
      $('#website-info').removeClass("hidden");
      $('#source').val("Website");
    });
  });
</script>
```

I check in google console and the word `value` appears, but never actually gets a value.  When I save a record the `source_type` field remains blank.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You may need to use `$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {...` . Have you tried that yet?  You may also need to use both turbolinks and just the regular ready, which looks like this `$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function() {...`.

Comment: I have removed turbolinks from my app. @rockwellrice

Comment: @rockwellrice I know it's running properly because the active class is getting added and taken away whenever the divs are clicked.

Comment: Sorry, one more question just to verify, when this gets submitted you can see that the `source_type` is blank right in the params sent over, correct?  I'm asking because the jquery looks right, I want to verify it isn't something like a missed param being whitelisted in the controller or something.

Comment: @RockwellRice Yup, `"source_type"=>""` is right there in the server log.

Comment: in your console, when you do `$("#source").val()`  what do you get ?

Comment: @RockwellRice Okay, that yields the right value.  ("Journal" or "book".)

Comment: I took this code and got it to work locally, although it is just the jquery on the front, not saving anything obviously, and I can't see anything wrong with the jquery.  If you open your inspector and click on one of those, do you see the value property getting added to the field with the correct value?

Comment: @RockwellRice No, that's the weird part.  It just says "value" in orange with no = and no actual value.

Comment: @Liz what happens if you remove all the code except what sets the value?  Just as a test, so just the on click function and setting the source value, is it the same behavior.  that code looks like it should work, something has to be interfering with it and I can't really tell what

Comment: @RockwellRice Tried, but with the same result!